# How to make route accessible only if there is query string

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have such route <Route path={`${match.path}/product/:id`} component={ProductPage} /> and if I go to http://localhost:3001/productPortal/product/5, then ProductPage is successfully shown. But I wanted to ensure that ProductPage is accessible ONLY IF we go to http://localhost:3001/productPortal/product/5?auth=123456. As you can see there is auth query parameter and if there is such query parameter then show ProductPage. Thus, should route look like <Route path={`${match.path}/product/:id?auth`} ?

Comment: Can not make router only accessible when there is a query parameter, but you check in that component if query auth if present or not, if yes then open it else redirect to log in or home page

Comment: I would go for manually return the NotFound component when there's not query string parameter.